# What happens to data stored in registers and on stack when OS switches to other tasks?

Tags: assembly, computer-science, cpu-architecture, low-level

I've been getting a bit interested in low level programming in the last couple of weeks. I wonder what happens to the data stored in proc registers, when the OS "decides" to switch to another task. Where is it stored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"Where"* heavily depends on underlying hardware architecture, but usually it's in main memory (RAM). For example Intel architecture has "[protected mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_mode)" (available on 268+ processors) that offers hardware-level tools to handle multi-tasking; for example the [task state segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_State_Segment) (which is a main memory segment) that holds CPU registers, among other data for this task.

Answer (score 4):

This operation is called a context switch.  The OS saves the contents of the registers and restores them when returning to the task.  The stack contents remain where they are, the new task is given a different area of memory for the stack.  When returning to the first task, the stack pointer is restored to point to the previous stack area.

Answer (score 0):

```
 I've been getting a bit interested in low level programming in the last 
 couple of weeks. I wonder what happens to the data stored in proc registers, 
 when the OS "decides" to switch to another task. Where is it stored?
```

The state of the CPU - that is the contents of the registers are stored in a **PCB** - *Process Control Block.* (for threads **TCB** - *Thread Control Block*) Its part of the memory that is allocated for the process - such as heap, stack etc.

*There is a dispather-program in the OS that handles these so called contextswitches and reacts to clockinterrupts. The switches between processes may happen every milisecond - it happends so often that the user perceive it as two programs execute at the same time - so called multitasking.*